# Phalcon use LIKE inside Query\Builder on two columns

Tags: phalcon

How can I select data from two columns using Query\Builder with 'LIKE' %something% and 'OR'.

I get no data if there is no match in column title despite the use of the OR, but there must be a match inside the column subtitle.

I'm currently doing this:

```
 $Query->andWhere(
    'MyData.title LIKE :searchValue: OR MyData.subtitle LIKE :searchValue:', [
        'searchValue' => '%' . $searchValue . '%',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks fine. Are you sure there is match? Maybe check what query is produced? You can easily add logs of all queries using 'db:beforeQuery' event.

Maybe you have some other conditions?

Comment: Yes, I've some other conditions but when I removed the first column it will give the data I searched for.

Comment: Then as i suggested - check what query is made in db:beforeQuery and execute it on your database.